# How to extract first and last lines in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, tail

File1

```
Sergio
Lionel
Luis
Andreas
Gerard
```

I want my stdout to have just

```
Sergio
Gerard
```

How can I do this using the tail command and piping?

Answer (score 18):

This should do the trick:

```
$ head -n 1 File1; tail -n 1 File1
```

Answer (score 10):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n -e '1p;$p' File1
```